# Set a value from a choosen option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I made a custom select and I want to set a value into div: valueHolder. I used the same code as for text, but it doesn't work.

I tried to use this code:

```
$('#adwin-select-category').find('div.valueHolder').val(target.val());
```

```js
var containerCategory = $('#adwin-select-category .dropContainer');

  $('#adwin-select-category').on('click', function(event)
  {
    var target = $(event.target);

    if(target.hasClass('valueHolder') || target.attr('id') === '#adwin-select-category')
    {
      containerCategory.show();
      document.getElementById("adwin-select-category").style.borderColor = "#FFAC0D";   
    }
    else if(target.hasClass('dropOption'))
    {
      $('#adwin-select-category').find('div.valueHolder').text(target.text());
      $('#adwin-select-category').find('div.valueHolder').val(target.val());
      containerCategory.hide();
      document.getElementById("adwin-select-category").style.borderColor = "#DDD";
      showElements();
    }
  });
```

```css
#adwin-select-category
{
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adwin-select-category" class="btn"> 
  <div class="valueHolder" value=""></div>
</div>
```

Example of the options:
    option 1

I want to set a value from the example option (value="1") to the valueHolder

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. `value` is not a standard attribute of a `div` element so you cannot use `$('div').val()`. This is only reserved for `form` fields. For elements other than `form` fields you can use `data-` attributes eg `data-value` and access the value, thus, `$(element).data('value')`.

Comment: @PeterKA `value` is available on all form fields (input, select, option, button, etc.), not just `input` elements. And for non-form field elements (such as `div`), you can just extract the `textContent` (`.text()` in JQuery) of the element directly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, you're absolutely right. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterKA I wanted to set value, because I want to make in js if institutions like: if($('#adwin-select-category').find('div.valueHolder').val()=="1") do something. So I want to get this "value" be assigned to a given option but still hidden, be just in backend. Is it ok to use data for it?

Comment: @PeterKA I want to do something like this: <option value="1">Ocean Wall</option>, because i want to distinguish it.

Comment: @PeterKA in my select valueHolder is the main div where the selected option is set, i also want to set something like value

Comment: In the `div` element if you change `value="1"` to `data-value="1"` then you can get the "value" of the element `div.valueHolder` using `$('div.valueHolder').data('value')`.

Comment: @PeterKA I wrote a setter: $('#adwin-select-category').find('div.valueHolder').data('value', target.data('value')); but it still doesn't set the value

Comment: <div class="dropOption" data-value="1">option</div> and here is an example of option

Comment: @MAXIM are you able to provide an updated minimum sample that clearly shows what is not working as expected?

Comment: @PeterKA i found the problem. Thank u a lot!

Comment: @MAXIM I'm glad you did. I was reviewing your html but as you saw the comments are not so good for posting code. Enjoy!

Comment: @PeterKA yes, its my first time here, but very nice. I will watch out for the code in the comments. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use `data-` attributes:

```js
$('#adwin-select-category > div').on('click', function(e) {
  var divVal = $(this).data('value');
  var divText = $(this).text();
  console.log( divVal );
  console.log( divText );
});
```

```css
#adwin-select-category
{
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adwin-select-category" class="btn"> 
  <div class="valueHolder" data-value="1">ONE</div>
  <div class="valueHolder" data-value="2">TWO</div>
  <div class="valueHolder" data-value="3">THREE</div>
  <div class="valueHolder" data-value="4">FOUR</div>
</div>
```